# Error while querying google sheets connected permanent table in BigQuery

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am trying to set up a scheduled query on BigQuery using new UI, which includes a reference to a table which is connected to a google sheet.

I am unable to schedule the query as BigQuery throws up this error:

> "Error while reading table: dataset.table_name, error message: Found corrupted data while opening file."

However, when I manually run the query or directly query the table using:

```
SELECT * From dataset.table_name
```

the query runs and shows accurate results, even though the error still pops up.

Is there a workaround to scheduling this query?

Answer (score 0):

There are some [known issues and limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#known_issues_and_limitations) for scheduling queries. For instance, you might need to update your credentials to query the Google Drive data. Moreover, you need to be sure that the destination table for your scheduled query is in the same region as the source of your data as this may give you this error message.

Hope it helps.